# neo4j relationships between PK and FK

Tags: neo4j

i have two csv files the first one is like

movies.csv

> movieId | title | genres

links.csv

> movieId | tmdbId | imdbId

ive tried this cypher query

```
 USING PERIODIC COMMIT 500
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM "file:///links.csv" AS row
WITH row
MATCH (movie:Movie {id: toInt(row.movieId)})
MERGE (link)-[r:LINK]->(movie)
ON CREATE SET r.tmdbId = toInt(row.tmdbId)
```

this didnt work for me, it doesnt create new label "LINK" or form the relationship correctly,,
i want to be able when i have a movieId to get its corresponding tmdbId
t've tried several methods but none of them worked, im new to neo4k and still familiarised with sql

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your usage of `link` is as a variable, not a label (you would use `:Link` if you wanted to create a new node with that label), and it's not really clear what your link is supposed to be, as you don't have any ids or any properties on it. It's also not clear what you need other nodes for, as a movie node can easily have properties for related ids (so you look up the :Movie node by its movieId and then get the tmdbId from that node).

If you could provide more details about your use cases, and what you want to model and how it's connected, that would help.

EDIT

Okay, so it sounds like you're modeling :Movies, and you also want :Link nodes that hold both tmdbId and imdbId properties. As mentioned above, in reality you should just set the properties on the :Movie node itself and not bother with :Link nodes at all, but this is for the sake of getting used to neo4j, so okay.

First of all, to make sure our matches are fast as we build these relationships, we need unique constraints on nodes through their unique IDs.

```
CREATE CONSTRAINT ON (m:Movie)
       ASSERT m.id IS UNIQUE

CREATE CONSTRAINT ON (l:Link)
       ASSERT l.tmdbId IS UNIQUE

CREATE CONSTRAINT ON (l:Link)
       ASSERT l.imdbId IS UNIQUE
```

Your import would be:

```
USING PERIODIC COMMIT 500
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM "file:///links.csv" AS row
WITH row
MATCH (movie:Movie {id: toInt(row.movieId)})
MERGE (link:Link{imdbId: toInt(row.imdbId), tmdbId: toInt(row.tmdbId)})
MERGE (link)-[:LINK]->(movie)
```

And a query to get the movie by one id would be:

```
MATCH (link:Link)-[:LINK]->(movie:Movie)
WHERE link.imdbId = 123
RETURN movie
```

You should be able to infer the query for going the opposite direction, starting with a movieId and traversing the :LINK relationship to the :Link node (you may want to change one of these, as having the same name for a node label and a relationship type might get confusing since you're new to this) to get the relevant ID.

Comment: ok, my bad,, right now i've loaded the movies.csv which contains the movieId, lets say "Toy Story" the movie has a movieId of 1,, heres how i want it to be  ,,,, Toy story --[:LINK]-->(ee:link) return ee.tmdbId,   sure the movieId on links.csv for toy story is 1. i just want to create a relationship whenever the movieId matches

Comment: ok ive loaded the links.csv successfully , now i hav this node for an example:  id:1 | title: Toy Story  .... and on Link label i have this node tmdbId 862
imdbId 0114709
movieId 1

Comment: i want to create relationship but not between only these two nodes but all nodes WHERE ee:Movie js:Link  where ee.movieID(PK) = js.movieId(FK)  that were very easy on sql

Comment: Updated my answer. The thing to keep in mind when starting with graph dbs is that the concept of foreign keys for joining isn't really needed or used, as relationships take the place of these. Where you once had foreign keys and primary keys between entities, you now have relationships between nodes, so your :Link nodes don't need to hold onto the movieId at all.

Comment: i am getting this semantic error,  Cannot merge node using null property value for tmdbId

Comment: So tmdbld may not be there for every movie. What about imdbId? Is that guaranteed to be there for every movie?

Comment: oh now i understand why am getting the error , thanks. yes i did it with IMDB only and it worked its really no big difference if i used TMDB or IMDB